# Camel route and MyBatis

Tags: apache-camel, dsl, mybatis

I am relatively new to Camel and i've been struggling with a problem with a simple route that uses MyBatis to "feed" an ActiveMQ queue.

My route is as follows:

```
public class SearchItemProductionRouteRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer://pollTheDatabase?delay=5000")
        .to("mybatis:selectSearchItem?statementType=SelectList&consumer.useIterator=true&consumer.onConsume=updateProcessingSearchItem")
        .to("bean:searchItemProcesser?method=process")
        .to("activemq:searchitemqueue");
    }
}
```

The mybatis query is working fine. The query itself brings 4 records from the database. My need is that each row should become a message in the queue, but instead, i get 1 message with all the 4 rows in it.

The searchItemProcessor just prints de body of the message (thats how i know that the message contains all 4 records).

These are the queries that the above route uses:

```
<select id="selectSearchItem" resultMap="result" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
    SELECT * FROM SEARCH_REQUEST_ITEM SRI WHERE SRI.STATUS = '1' 
</select>

<update id="updateProcessingSearchItem">
    UPDATE SEARCH_REQUEST_ITEM SET STATUS = 2,   
    UPDATEDIN=SYSDATE, UPDATEDBY='XDRBATCH' 
    WHERE ID = #{ID}
</update>
```

If anyone can shed some light over this i'll be thankful!

EDIT:

Just found one workaround using the Splitter EIP. First i created this class:

```
public class XdrMessageSplitterBean {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public List<HashMap> splitBody(Object body) {
        return (List<HashMap>) body;
    }
}
```

Then add it to the route:

```
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer://pollTheDatabase?delay=5000")
        .to("mybatis:selectSearchItem?statementType=SelectList&consumer.useIterator=true&consumer.onConsume=updateProcessingSearchItem")
        .split().method("xdrMessageSplitterBean", "splitBody")
        .to("bean:searchItemProcesser?method=process")
        .to("activemq:searchitemqueue");
    }
```

The bean must be declared in the camel-context.xml file:

```
    <bean id="xdrMessageSplitterBean" name="xdrMessageSplitterBean"
    class="package.of.bean.XdrMessageSplitterBean" />
```

It works, but does not feel right. If anyone has any suggestion it will be very welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consume from mybatis directly, and specify the polling frequency. You dont need the timer for that. There is a delay option you can use to set = 5000 for 5 seconds frequency.

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("mybatis:selectSearchItem?statementType=SelectList&consumer.useIterator=true&consumer.onConsume=updateProcessingSearchItem&delay=5000")
        .split().method("xdrMessageSplitterBean", "splitBody")
        .to("bean:searchItemProcesser?method=process")
        .to("activemq:searchitemqueue");
    }
```

Comment: Hi @claus-ibsen, thanks for your reply. I followed your suggestion so that my route could be even simpler. Guess what, it solved all my problems. I don't understand why but adding the delay option and removing the timer, made the other options (consumer.useIterator and consumer.onConsumer) work as they should. Do you have any idea ? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes the consumer.xxx options only work if the endpoint is declared as a consumer eg in the from in the route DSL. When you declare the endpoint in the "to" in the DSL, then its a producer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you found the right way to do it. You should not consider it a workaround.

Actually, since mybatis returns a List I'm not even sure you need the "XdrMessageSplitterBean".

Comment: Hi @Petter, thanks for your reply. I've tried without the custom splitter bean and it also worked (i've changed `.method("xdrMessageSplitterBean", "splitBody")` to `.body()`). Although it works i am still intrigued about the mbatis configuration string; in my example the `&consumer.useIterator=true&consumer.onConsume=updateProcessingSearchItem` has no impact, it does not work. Nor it treats the results independently neither it executes the `updateProcessingSearchItem` query. Do you have some thoughts about that ?